# .height reload div height multiple times

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use an increase font jquery script but when the font size is increased I dont know how to make jquery reload the div size so that a scroll bar appears/disappears. I've got tantilisingly close but my code only works the first time I click, subsequently it doesnt update. Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
$j(document).ready(function(){
  // Reset Font Size
  var originalFontSize = $j('html').css('font-size');
    $j(".resetFont").click(function(){
    $j('html').css('font-size', originalFontSize);
  });
  // Increase Font Size
  $j(".increaseFont").click(function(){
    var currentFontSize = $j('html').css('font-size');
    var currentFontSizeNum = parseFloat(currentFontSize, 10);
    var newFontSize = currentFontSizeNum*1.2;
    $j('html').css('font-size', newFontSize);
    $j("#content").height(auto);
    return false;
  });
  // Decrease Font Size
  $j(".decreaseFont").click(function(){
    var currentFontSize = $j('html').css('font-size');
    var currentFontSizeNum = parseFloat(currentFontSize, 10);
    var newFontSize = currentFontSizeNum*0.8;
    $j('html').css('font-size', newFontSize);
    return false;
  });
});
</script>
```

I added this $j("#content").height(auto); to the end of increase height. From what I gather the first time the function is called it sets the height to auto which works. But then on subsequent clicks the height is already set to auto so it doesn't make a difference. If anyone could show me how to modify my code I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$j("#content").css({'height' : 'auto'});
```

or more information is required.

what's the css for `#content` AND have you any explicit heights set on any other elements in your CSS?

Comment: no that didn't work :( My css for #content is:

#content {
 height: 100%;
 margin: none;
}

The whole page is set to percentage heights, does this make a difference?

Comment: yes it might, if the page is 100% height (based on `html, body {height: 100%;}`?)  it's possible that the larger font-size will increase it beyond that, however once you set height to auto there's nothing left for other heights to inherit from -  however without seeing the whole page structure I wouldn't like to say how restrictive the heights are being to this set up

Comment: yes the page and html are set to 100%. How might I edit the following code to load only a particular div

$j("#content").load("target.html");

Instead of 'target' how would i define a div contained within 'target'?